# How to add a new column with auto increment ,increment factor, min-value and max value in psql?

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

I have table t1 and I would like to add a new column **app_id** with the properties given below

- auto increment
- increment factor(increment by 4)
- min-value/initial value(100)
- max-value(2000)

I have tried

```
alter table t4 
add column app_id int not null auto_increment = 100 ;
```

but which is not worked.is it possible to add such a column with the properties mentioned above?

Comment: what happens when max-value is reached?

Comment: @McNets when max value is reached, then which is need to be stop there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you can use [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altersequence.html) to increase `app_id` value.
Please noted if the sequence reach to its `maxvalue`, you will face this error `ERROR:  nextval: reached maximum value of sequence` .

For example

```
create table t1 (a int, b int);

create sequence seq_t1
increment by 4
minvalue 100
maxvalue 2000;

alter table t1 add column app_id int default nextval('seq_t1');
insert into t1(a) select generate_series(1, 100) ;

  a  | b | app_id
-----+---+--------
   1 |   |    100
   2 |   |    104
   3 |   |    108
   4 |   |    112
   5 |   |    116
   6 |   |    120
   7 |   |    124
```

Comment: good idea...!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [POSTGRES SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html).

```
CREATE IF NOT EXISTS SEQUENCE MySerial
    INCREMENT 4
    START WITH 100
    MAXVALUE 2000
    NO CYCLE
    OWNED BY TABLE.COLUMN_NAME;
```

Then you can add a default value of nextval('MySerial') in your field definition, or you can use:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (nextval('MySerial'), ...);
```

You can get last value used with:

```
select curval('MySerial');
```